# Bootstrap Shopify navigation won't collapse

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4, navigation, shopify

I am currently making a custom Shopify menu using Bootstrap, and I am experiencing some rather strange problems. I can't seem to be able to collapse the content inside my menu.

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    {%for link in linklists[settings.main_linklist].links %}
        {%if link.links == blank%}
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{link.url}}">{{link.title}}</a>
            </li>
        {%endif%}
        {%if link.links != blank%}
            <li class="nav-item dropdown dropdown-mobile">
                <a class="nav-link scroll-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-mobile" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Shop
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mobile full-width" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    {%for childlink in link.links%}
                        <div class="row text-center w-100">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-mobile" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown{{childlink.title}}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{childlink.title}}</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mobile full-width">
                                    {% for sublink in childlink.links %}
                                        <p class="text-center">{{sublink.title}}</p>
                                    {%endfor%}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {%endfor%}
                </div>
            </li>
        {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

In other words, I am not able to collapse the parents of the `{% for sublink in childlink.links %}` content using this:

`<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-mobile" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown{{childlink.title}}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{childlink.title}}</a>`

Picture Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `dropdown-item` class to the child you want to collapse.
Instead of

```
<p class="text-center">{{sublink.title}}</p>
```

use

```
<p class="dropdown-item text-center">{{sublink.title}}</p>
```